# C# border style changes to windows 10 when I add ribbon

Tags: c#, forms, ribbon

I want to use a ribbon but when I add it my border becomes flat.
I use `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm` as form
I've tried disabling `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`
I have tried placing the ribbon in a panel. That works but the gradient is not smooth.

Wrong border with ribbon

[image]

The border I want

[image]

Comment: That's the Windows 10 visual style. If you want to use advanced visual styles, you need to use *all* of them - you can't pick and choose. For more information, have a look at MSDN, it gives tons of information on how the styling works. And for my two cents, I don't like applications that try to push their own styles on me - just use the system defaults, that's how you get a consistent look.

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs